# Como fazer um botão com link em AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Como fazer um botão com link/redirecionamento em AngularJS?

html

```
<button class="btn btn-success" href="go('/cadastro.html')">Cadastra-se</button>
```

config

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    .when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'views/login.html',
      controller     : 'LoginCtrl',
    })

    .when('/cadastro', {
      templateUrl : 'views/cadastro.html',
      controller     : 'CadastroCtrl',
    })

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até onde sei, a tag `button` não possui o atributo `href`.

Um outro ponto, se você deseja navegar até a rota */cadastro* , você precisa mudar seu `location` para *'/cadastro'* , retirando o HTML do caminho. Lembre-se que você está acessando uma rota, e não um caminho físico até seu HTML.

Se você utilizar o código abaixo, deve acessar a rota *'/cadastro'* conforme configurado em seu módulo.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#/cadastro')">Cadastra-se</a>
```

Caso queira utilizar um botão acessando um método de seu controller, deve fazer semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="go(/cadastro)">Cadastra-se</button>
```

E em seu controller:

```
$scope.go = function(path){
     $location.path(path);
}
```

[O objeto $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) deve ser incluído como uma dependência do código acima. Ele tem como objetivo lhe dar uma interface para acessar a URL do browser. Qualquer modificação feita na URL irá refletir no objeto `$location`, e vice-versa.

Comment: Cara, consegui usando o <a class="btn btn-success" href="#/cadastro')">Cadastra-se</a>, porém o outro, tentei fazer o que você disse e não deu certo. Qual controller você se refere? CadastroCtrl?

Comment: @GustavoSevero no controller ao qual o seu botão pertence. Se seu botão está dentro de uma div <div ng-controller"CadastroCtrl">[...] então sim, no CadastroCtrl

Answer (score 0):

ficaria assim:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="cadastro" >
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <span >
    Cadastrar
  </span>
</button>
```

Ele irá usar sua routa especificada no seu config para redirecionar.

Answer (score 0):

Este seu código já está quase pronto. Só falta adicionar a função no controller para trocar de rota:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
    $location.path( path ); 
 };
```

Mas, como aparentemente você está utilizando o bootstrap, acredito seja possível você utilizar a tag  ao invés de button, desta forma:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="cadastro.html'">Cadastra-se</a>
```

Assim, você não precisa da função no controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla**

Via Javascript

```
<input type="button" 
    onclick="location.href='http://servidor.com.br';" 
    value="Visitar servidor.com.br" 
/>
```

Via form action

```
<form action="http://servidor.com.br">
    <input type="submit" value="Visitar servidor.com.br" />
</form>
```

---

**Angular**

Via diretiva:

```
.directive( 'goClick', function ( $location ) {
  return function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
    var path;

    attrs.$observe( 'goClick', function (val) {
      path = val;
    });

    element.bind( 'click', function () {
      scope.$apply( function () {
        $location.path( path );
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Uso:

```
<button go-click="http://servidor.com.br">Visitar servidor.com.br</button>
```

([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15848150/1845714))